# Aruba OS equivalent for default interface

Tags: interface, aruba

I need to reset or default an interface on an Aruba switch. This may be the same for HP procurve switches, but I am not sure. On Cisco, the command would be `default interface` in global config mode. Is there an equivalent command for Aruba OS?

Comment: While in the interface configuration, is there a default command? Ex.: `interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1` - `[HP-GigabitEthernet1/0/1]default` - `This command will restore the default settings. Continue? [Y/N]:y` There's also an `undo` command, where you can put undo in front of almost any command, just like `no`.

Comment: There's no default command in interface config or global config that I can see.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a simple command to reset an interface to default.

If it's any help you can quickly display the current config by running `show config interface n` - saves you from searching for the somewhat scattered relevant lines in the config file.

Answer (score 4):

ArubaOS version 7.4

When working with Aruba Mobility Switches, there would be few instances where a port has to be bought to its default config state, so the new profiles can be applied again. Removing each associated profile would take time and gives a chance of configuration error. This one command suggested below would help us greatly:

Reset to default config with a single command:

```
(config) #no interface gigabitethernet 0/0/10
```

Comment: This does not appear to be working the same way for AOS 16.04.0009. "no interface ethernet [port number]" lists about 30 commands, but by itself is incomplete.

Comment: @Yanzzee i see i'm on version 7.4 so that might be a problem.